# Telerik UI For WinForms RadMessageBox font size

Tags: telerik

Is there a way to increase the default font size of the RadMessageBox for the whole application without having to create a custom theme?

If not, how to just increase the font on the default theme in Visual Style Builder?  I tried just increasing the label and button font sizes, but the style builder reset the whole form that hosts the message box to look very plain and cutting the text of the label (see attached screenshot).

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you create a custom control? Perhaps you can use [FlexibleMessageBox](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/601900/FlexibleMessageBox-A-flexible-replacement-for-the).

Comment: Thanks Odrai,  since I only want to increase the font size I was hoping to find a simpler approach.  Ultimately, I may have to do that though.

Comment: I have posted an answer in the message below. If you have any questions, feel free to ask them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to customize the font for all RadMessageBoxes within an application.

1. Implement a method ('SetTelerikControlStyles') which is called before any form and/or RadMessageBox is created. You only need to call this method once!
2. Add the following lines of code in the created method of step 1:

   ```
   RadMessageBox.Instance.FormElement.TitleBar.Font = new Font("Calibri", 25f);
   RadMessageBox.Instance.Controls["radLabel1"].Font = new Font("Calibri", 50f, FontStyle.Regular);
   ```

The *FormElement.TitleBar.Font*, as the name already reveals, is the title bar of the RadMessageBox.

Telerik is using dynamic named controls, so in this case *radLabel1* represents the RadMessageBox text area.

---

Complete Program.cs sample:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using Telerik.WinControls;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            SetTelerikControlStyles();

            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }

        private static void SetTelerikControlStyles()
        {
            RadMessageBox.Instance.FormElement.TitleBar.Font = new Font("Calibri", 25f);

            // I added this additional check for safety, if Telerik modifies the name of the control.
            if (RadMessageBox.Instance.Controls.ContainsKey("radLabel1"))
            {
                RadMessageBox.Instance.Controls["radLabel1"].Font = new Font("Calibri", 50f, FontStyle.Regular);
            }
        }
    }
}
```